# AVPlayerViewController black screen when swiping on iOS 11

Tags: swift, video, ios11, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm using `AVPlayerViewController` to play a video file (H.264, AAC, MP4-Container) on an iPad-App.
Everything is working in iOS 10. And also in iOS 11 it plays the video correctly.

But in iOS 11, when I start swiping in any direction, it immediately blacks out the video and also mutes audio. It also shows a loading indicator next to the timeline on the bottom.

Also it ignores the `allowsPictureInPicturePlayback` property, so it doesn't show the PIP-Button on iOS 11.

This is the code I use:

```
avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
avPlayerController?.showsPlaybackControls = true
avPlayerController?.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true
avPlayerController?.player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl as URL)
avPlayerController?.player?.play()            

self.present(self.avPlayerController!, animated: true, completion: nil)            

avPlayerController?.player?.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onVideoCompleted), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.avPlayerController!.player?.currentItem)
```

And this function to close the Video Player at the end of the video:

```
func onVideoCompleted(notification:Notification) {
    self.avPlayerController?.player = nil
    self.avPlayerController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When the screen blacks out I get this in the Console:

```
AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) 
>>>> -[AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl 
outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device discovery 
mode to DiscoveryMode_Presence (client: MyAppName)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I found the mistake:
To close the Airplay video playback when pressing "Done" I used this code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if avPlayerController?.isBeingDismissed ?? false {
        avPlayerController?.player = nil
    }
}
```

But with iOS 11, Apple added a feature to close the Video Player via a swipe gesture. So when I swipe, the `viewWillAppear` function gets called.
Putting this code inside `viewDidAppear` fixed this and preserved the AirPlay-Fix.

Comment: I am facing somewhat a similar issue which only happens when I switch from MPMoviePlayerViewController to AVPlayerViewController. 

I get the following error message in the console after tapping the Done button of MPMoviePlayer:  
`Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None (client: APPNAME)[Playback]❗️Failed to queue any items.`  

After this, even when I try the above-mentioned solution by setting the player to nil, the AVPLayer video cannot play and is frozen.

This happens only when the device is connected via AirPlay.

Comment: Thanks for this. I wish I had known that iOS 11 added this in. I was following a sample put out by Apple, IRT to video playback, and they kill off video playback in the presenting views' `viewWillAppear` method, too.