# AVPlayer is not playing in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation, avplayer

I am facing an issue with AVPlayer in iOS 11. The same code is working perfectly on iOS 10. I used DRM for playing the video.

I am getting below warning :

```
  2017-11-22 20:48:09.237095+0530 AppName[9113:3782887] [] <<<< 
  AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -
  [AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl 
  outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device 
  discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None (client: AppName)
  2017-11-22 20:48:09.266561+0530 AppName[9113:3782887] Presenting view 
  controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged 
  <Nettkino.PlayerViewController: 0x103f0a4b0>.
  2017-11-22 20:48:09.272713+0530 AppName[9113:3782887] [framework] 
  CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)'
  2017-11-22 20:48:09.272730+0530 AppName[9113:3782887] [framework] 
  CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)'
  2017-11-22 20:48:09.285772+0530 AppName[9113:3782887] [] <<<< 
  AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -
  [AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl 
  outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device 
  discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_Presence (client: AppName)
```

Please guide me. I am  unable to solve this issue from last 3 days. Please let me know if you need more information about the app I used, I'll update my question.

Comment: Can you please post anywhere sample xcode project which reproduces your issue?

Comment: That is not my sample project. That is my full project which i cant share

Comment: I do not ask you to share the whole project. Can you CREATE another small xcode project with dummy data which fails to play

Comment: I used DRM for video security & have so many connection with player . For creating url I have to do so many things. So My question is why the player is not playing in iOS 11, but its playing in iOS 10.What is this "Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None "

Comment: @SRNayak Did you try answers in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46321860/avplayerviewcontroller-black-screen-when-swiping-on-ios-11?

Comment: I had an experience when I tried to play a 4K video on unsupported iPhone. Which was shown as black screen. Try to play a simple video for test

Comment: One of the warnings says "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged". Apparently you do this and it worked in iOS10 but no longer in iOS11?

Comment: Yes its working in iOS 10 and not in iOS 11 :(

Comment: I searched all question and answers in SO, but not getting any solution for this. Please Please help me out from this problem.

Comment: add code snippet for clear understanding

Comment: Not a lot to go on, but "Invalid asset name supplied (null)" is your biggest clue.

Answer (score 0):

Without code we can get the exact error descriptions. Please Post the Player creation and the steps you are using to play the file. Then only we will execute and get back to you.

Comment: You should comment on the question instead posting an answer with request for code

Comment: It is a new account, so i am not able to comment without 50 reputations. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Ah, good reason.. It's interesting to ask in meta (if it's not been asked before) what should be done in such situation